# How to cross compile hostapd for Xilinx Zynq?

Tags: openssl, arm, cross-compiling, xilinx, hostapd

I am following [this link](http://wiki.beyondlogic.org/index.php?title=Cross_Compiling_iw_wpa_supplicant_hostapd_rfkill_for_ARM#OpenSSL) to cross compile the iw tools.  I can compile `libnl, iw, openssl`, and installed them in CentOS.  For Open SSL, I used `./configure Linux-generic32 --prefix=/usr/arm-xilinx/linux-gnueabi`, so it should install to that directory.

When I try to compile hostapd, I followed exact steps except `make CC=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc`
 and got this

```
../src/crypto/tls_openssl.c:19:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
```

I think it should be caused by not knowing where is openssl installed to.  So how do I tell the make to look at /usr/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/include/openssl instead of /usr/include/openssl for the openssl?

Answer (score 0):

You can tell your Makefile by using CFLAGS for the header files and LDFLAGS for the libraries.

```
make CFLAGS=-I<include/path> LDFLAGS=-L<lib/path>
```